For $X_n\ge 0$ prove $P(\bigcup\{X_n=0\}\cup\{\lim{X_n}=\infty\})=1$ if $P(\bigcup\{X_n=0\}|X_1,...,X_n)\ge\delta_x$ almost surely on $\{X_n\le x\}$
Let $X_n\ge 0$ and $D=\bigcup\{X_n=0\}$, and suppose that for all $x>0\in \Bbb{R}$ there exists $\delta(x)> 0$, such that for all $n$, $P(D|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)\ge\delta(x)$ almost surely on the event $\{X_n\le x\}$, then $P(D\cup\{\lim_{n\to \infty}{X_n}=\infty\})=1$.
What I am having trouble with the most is the notation $P(D|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ which I didn't use a lot. Also, intuitively I see why this is the case, but I can't figure out how to rigorously show that.
I attempted showing that $E(1_{D\cup\{\infty\}^{C}})=0$, but how can I show it using the right transitions? I mean of course if this $X_n$ is bounded by $\sup_n X_n$, then $P(D|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)\ge \delta (\sup{X_n})$, which would imply the above equation. However, I can't write it down correctly, and I feel like I am missing a key argument of something like that. Could you please help?
The lecture preceding this discussed Doob's representation, Levy's 0-1 Law, Lévy's Convergence Upwards and Downwards, and Uniformly Integrable Variables/Matringales.
